# What is the arcade game played in the "The Boys Next Door" movie?

Tags: identify-this-game, coin-op

This is from the movie *[The Boys Next Door](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090770/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt)* (1985). The character is playing an arcade game.

[image]

There is the name, but is impossible to read. I read "mrrruders" but searching on the net nothing came out. It is not properly a video game, but an electro-mechanical game, with a "laser gun" you shoot the "monsters".

Comment: the one on the left is Pole Position II :)

Comment: The "R"'s are not all the same size, which suggests that not all of them are R's, and the only other letter they can be is A. (Which clearly leads you to the title of "Mrarudeas". /s)

Comment: It's a lot more legible if you were playing video games during that era -- that style of typeface was pretty common.

Comment: For the computer connection, https://ipdb.org/machine.cgi?id=6498 says it’s built around a Motorola MC68701 programmable microcontroller, basically an EPROM 6801.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It’s Bally Midway’s 1984 game, [Midnight Marauders](https://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=10615):

[image: Panel from the Midnight Marauders game, with the Bally Midway logo and stylised guns]

As you say it isn’t a video game, it’s an electromechanical game. It’s similar to Space Invaders: the player is supposed to shoot alien tanks and spaceships using a light gun, and must prevent the alien spaceships from reaching the surface.

Comment: I think I've played that game in the pinball area of Galloping Ghost arcade in Brookfield, IL.